# C# md5 hash not matching node generated md5 hash

Tags: c#, node.js, md5

I'm trying to generate an md5 hash and store it as a hex string via C# program (not related to passwords!), but I need to replicate an existing node method. When I check my generated hashes against ones generated by node they do not match. I suspect it has something to do with encoding, but I've tried both UTF8 and ASCII and am not getting much luck. Any help appreciated.

The node method is below:

```
 public static hash(...data: string[]): string {

        var md5sum = createHash('md5');
        md5sum.update(data?.join() ?? '');

        var hash = md5sum.digest('hex');
        return hash;

    }
```

C# method

```
 public static string CalculateHash(string[] inputs)
        {
            var hashInput = String.Join("", inputs);

            using (var md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create())
            {
                byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hashInput);
                byte[] hashBytes = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);
                var sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < hashBytes.Length; i++)
                {
                    sb.Append(hashBytes[i].ToString("x2"));
                }
                return sb.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Looks good. What's your input and output?

Comment: Fundamentally cryptographic hashes apply to bytes, not text. It's clear how you're deriving the bytes-to-hash from the text in the .NET - do you know what the Node code uses?

Comment: *"I suspect it has something to do with encoding, but I've tried both UTF8 and ASCII and am not getting much luck"* This is called [shotgun debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shotgun_debugging). It can work, but it's tedious and, honestly, a bit unprofessional. I recommend to use a *methodic* approach instead. Don't make random changes, try to understand *what the code does* and *why* it does this. For example, you will notice that both methods yield the same result if fed with a single-element array. What does that tell you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScripts `data?.join()` [joins strings with a comma](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), i.e. `["Hello", "World"].join()` yields `"Hello,World"`.

In C#, you explicitly join the strings without separator, so `String.Join("", new[] {"Hello", "World"})` yields `"HelloWorld"`.

If you change your C# code line to

```
var hashInput = String.Join(",", inputs);
```

both methods yield the same result ([C# fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ahFOLe), [JavaScript fiddle](https://tio.run/##VY@xDsIwDETn9iuiLk0lyMaE2PkDBsQQJaZNlcbFSSoQ4ttLQjsUj77nu3MvJ@kVmTHsHWqYZ3aPTgWDjnXSd1wIoWWQDXuXRTFJYopeY0B2YgSPaAh4vWzq5liydTI36IOPQ@IWWSgCGeCcPeukbfEFFXFMScBznOjRON4k5s8zN0qOK69NCz7wuoPn1o0gRFrar@efslToPFoQFlv@@@tancFarHasuiBZXd1S2jx/AQ)).

Comment: Thanks for the help - I feel like an idiot, but I'll be leaving this as a testament to not trying to rush through something on a Sunday morning before a family outing :) Excuses won't help, but I was unable to get the node environment running locally in order to correctly debug